# order by clause is different with CHAR(8) AND NVARCHAR(8) columns with Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I am using SQL Server 2016 and i have the same table structure setup in two databases ie database 1 and database 2. The table structure is the same on both tables for table T, the primary key columns are of char(8) on one and NVARCHAR(8) on the other.

- The primary key column is of type CHAR(8) on table T in database 1
- The primary key column is of type NVARCHAR(8) on table T in database
  2

My primary key has keys as below, they have special characters

```
'........
'/*-/*-  
'/////   
'/////...
+65+965+
       //  
 - -
```

**Issue**

When I order by the primary key in the two tables i get different order of the keys. How can this be resolved without having to change the column type? 
I tried casting the column to the other type but that did not help with ordering.

Comment: May be a red herring, but have you verified that the collation is the same for this column in both databases?

Comment: If the data is the same and the collations are the same, then they should sort the same.  My assumption is that the data is not the same.

Comment: Note that there are Unicode alternate values for some common ANSI/ASCII punctuation, such as periods and hyphens. If the system with Nvarchar is storing the Unicode versions instead of the ANSI  versions, these would store differently. You can compare by using the `ASCII()` function on all the characters in the varchar strings and the `UNICODE()` function on the Nvarchar strings and seeing if the actual values of the characters differ.

Comment: See the "SQL Server collations" section on this page. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/collations/collation-and-unicode-support?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: I am using the same coallations in both the databases SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS

Comment: yep - and that is a SQL collation so the link above applies